# ERROR | Exception occured: org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInvocationNotAllowedException: Behavior rejected interface invocation

Tags: java, spring, wicket, wicket-8

I upgraded my application from Wicket 6.x to Wicket 8.x and also replaced **Button** and **AjaxButton** class to **IndicatingAjaxButton** class. I am getting below error on click of the submit button link.

```
IndicatingAjaxButton btnSubmit = new IndicatingAjaxButton("submit") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            AjaxLazyLoadPanel panel = new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("cnt2") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Override
                public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String markupId) {
                    try {
                        return new ContractClassPanel(markupId, null, getIdentifier(), getTimelines());
                    } catch (ContractException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("", e);
                    }
                }
            };
            panel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            form.setVisible(false);
            AbstractContractsClassPage.this.replace(panel);
            target.focusComponent(AbstractContractsClassPage.this);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            super.onError();
        }           
    };
```

ERROR | Exception occured:
org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInvocationNotAllowedException: Behavior rejected interface invocation. Component: [AjaxButton [Component id = submit]] Behavior: org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton$1@591549f6
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:276)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerRequestHandler.java:222)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.respond(ListenerRequestHandler.java:208)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:914)
at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:282)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:275)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:206)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:204)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Show us your code related to this button. The error says that the invocation of AjaxButton#onClick() is rejected. This could be because it is invisible or disabled.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the response. I have added the code in the question and also added the solution in the answer.

Comment: After changing the method name from focusComponent() to add(), it resolved the issue.
target.add(AbstractContractsClassPage.this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed code to add a current class (AbstractContractsClassPage.this) in the form. And I called the wrong method focusComponent() instead of add().

I got the solution after calling the add() method instead of the focusComponent().

```
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            AjaxLazyLoadPanel panel = new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("cnt2") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Override
                public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String markupId) {
                    try {
                        return new ContractClassPanel(markupId, null, getIdentifier(), getTimelines());
                    } catch (ContractException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("", e);
                    }
                }
            };
            panel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            form.setVisible(false);
            AbstractContractsClassPage.this.replace(panel);
            **target.add(AbstractContractsClassPage.this);**
        }
```

Comment: AjaxRequestTarget#add(Page) re-renders the whole page. Are you sure you need Ajax button at all ?

Comment: Yes, @martin-g still we need AjaxButton but I need process image on button click so using IndicatingAjaxButton class.

Comment: Hi @martin-g, please vote for this question. Hope this can help others to resolve their issues.